# Facebook Application - FB like - URL of the App

Tags: facebook

I have a like button on my page that I'm hosting as a FB app. Question is: Leaving the data-href blank on the like, sets my canvas url "www.example.com/page.aspx" for liking. Window.location.href or window.top.location all point to the canvas URL.

I want the users to like the app URL instead of the canvas URL. Anyway I can get this in the code behind? or in javascript? I do not want to specify this, because I want to do this for multiple applications each one to point to their own app url to like.

Comment: Please be more specific. In order to help we need some details including the SDK that you use, CMS, scripting language etc.

Comment: I'm using the Javascript API.

Comment: Alexandru: I've found that window.top.location.href gives the value of the top most parent. My problem is being able to record this in javascript and pass it to the code behind even before the actual page is loaded. I need this to get the URL to set for the fb like plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to somehow initialize the app in order to work with it so in your config you should have a canvas name (or namespace).
Another method would be to query the graph-api for convas details. The query should look something like this:

```
var app_data = FB.api("/you_app_id");
```

You should test it first with [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) . And also remember that this is an expensive call if you're doing it on each page request. You will get an array with all the info about your currently loaded app including the canvas name. Having the canvas name you can form the app URL like this: http://apps.facebook.com/your-canvas-name

Comment: Thanks Alexandru. Interesting way of doing it. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow find the parent URL of the Iframe that the app is loaded into?

Comment: The parent URL would be the app url which should be like this: apps.facebook.com/[your_canvas_namespace]and the namespace you have from quering FB.api like above

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No!

Longer answer: You cannot get any information from a frame in another domain. This is for security purposes. So if you try:

```
console.log(window.top.location.href);
```

...when the frames are in the same domain, you'll get the url. Otherwise, you'll get a security exception.